# Scopes and "sum"-query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use the same query logic multiple times in my Laravel 5 application. I know there are scopes to reuse this logic easily. But this doesn't seem to work with a sum-query.

```
public function scopeProfit($query)
{
    return $query -> sum('in') - $query -> sum('out');
}
```

In my app I have long lines of code like

```
# 'latest' is a scope to filter sales of the last three months
$profit = $user -> sales() -> latest() -> sum('in') - $user -> sales() -> latest() -> sum('out');
```

This is one of the shorter lines I use multiple lines. It isn't a real problem but I would love to shorten some lines, like:

```
$profit = $user -> sales() -> latest() -> profit();
```

Is there a way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with scoping this sort of thing is that query scopes expect the query to be returned. When you run `->sum()` you're actually performing a special kind of "[aggregate](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bab61e0217cf18b96b6f3da1da229764ec1171c4/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1607)" query and as such there's no way to bake this kind of functionality into query scopes.

It's also worth mentioning that you're performing two queries in your two `sum()` functions above when the same can easily be achieved with just one query:

```
$profit = $user->sales()->latest()->sum(DB::raw('in - out'));
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for :P But thanks for shorten my query. What is the best place to store such functions to make them reusable?

Comment: Sort of depends on how your architecture is set up. Quick and dirty solution is to add a helper function to your Eloquent model. `$user->getSalesProfit()` which just does what you've got there. A more thorough and better-architected solution is difficult to get into right now in the scope of this question.